# sharepoint 2013 date format issue dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a web part with sharepoint 2013 , In this webpart I have a text box that inserting a date into a colum named Fstdate in the SQL server 2012 database ,

after publishing i've tried to insert the date in format dd/mm/yyyy , I found it in the database mm/dd/yyyy

Example :
I'm tring to insert 12/10/2016 as 12 is the day , and 10 is the month 
I found that 10 is the day and 12 is the month

I solved the problem by changing the date format of the regional settings of the server to dd/mm/yyyy

I need to insert the date as dd/mm/yyyy , without changing the main date format of the server and let it mm/dd/yyyy

Anyway to solve this issue , or changing my code ???

Comment: if you need to make the change in an SQL statement then
`CONVERT(datetime, yourdatefield , 104)`

Comment: This is my parameter , I need to specify a format in the asp datasource <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Fstdate" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a textbox in your webpart for dates...
The correct way to work with date inputs in a SharePoint WebPart is making use of the following control:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl LocaleId="1043" runat="server" ID="PubDate" />
```

As you see, you can have a LocalId as attribute which will modify the way the date is showed